# Is there something like Jack Audio for Video management

Tags: video, jack

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 and Jack Audio Connection Kit.

I wonder if there is something like Jack Audio Connection Kit, but... To Video apps.

I mean... Some server that lets us the same connections that Jack lets in the audio domain, but... In the video domain.

Is there something like this? Where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is in the works, it is called [PipeWire](https://pipewire.org/). Jupiter Broadcasting had a good episode on it. It’s not near complete though, and I have never messed with it. Gstreamer can provide some sort of functionality in this area as well, their website has tutorials. I’m very excited to see where the PipeWire project goes, it’s going to greatly improve multimedia creation on Linux! https://linuxunplugged.com/272